# Фильтр jQuery. Помогите разобраться в 1 моменте и оцените подход/код

Tags: jquery

У меня есть такой html:

```
<input placeholder="Поиск..." id="myFilter" type="text"></a>
<ul id="myUL">    
  <li><a title="Красный цвет">Text</a></li>
  <li><a title="Синий цвет">Text</a></li>
  <li><a title="Зеленый цвет">Text</a></li>
  <li><a title="Белый цвет">Text</a></li>
  <li><a title="Красный цвет">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Под него я написал фильтр:

```
var filterInput = $('input#myFilter');
var filterTarget = $('ul#myUL');
var filterText;

$(filterInput).keyup(function () {
    filterText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(filterTarget).find('a:not([title^="'+filterText+'"])').css({'display':'none'});
    $(filterTarget).find('a[title^="'+filterText+'"]').css({'display':'block'});
    if (filterText == "") {
        $(filterTarget).find('a').css({'display':'block'});
    }
});

jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
    return jQuery(a).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(m[3].toLowerCase())>=0;
};
```

Как мне в фильтре менять стили `<li>` не используя `parent()`? Например для таких случаев:

```
<ul id="myUL">    
  <li><div><a title="Красный цвет">Text</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

Теперь вот этот момент `[title^="'+filterText+'"]`.
Когда я написал вот так без двойных кавычек `[title^='+filterText+']` возникла ошибка когда в `input` вводишь второе слово через пробел.
Значение `input`: красный цвет

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [title^=красный цвет]
```

В общем сделал как в 1 варианте и все заработало. Но когда в `input` что-то набираешь и удаляешь все элементы скрывались. Поэтому решил добавить проверку на пустое значение `input`. Правильно ли я сделал? Можно ли сделать как-то правильнее? И есть ли у Вас какие-то замечания/рекомендации в целом?